Diagnosing re-direct of WP Ajax calls
I am seeking the best way to diagnose what is causing my Ajax calls to /wp_admin/admin-ajax.php to be re-directed to my site's homepage.  I'm writing a new custom plugin for our site, following the pattern of another (working) plugin that uses admin-ajax.  The existing plugin is working fine, but my new plugin's calls to admin-ajax always get re-directed home.
I have already corrected what seemed the most likely culprit.  We have a login-re-direct plugin that sends users to the right landing page based on their role, so I updated that to include a test for DOING_AJAX before running the re-direct logic, but that did not help:
    if (is_admin() || !$post || DOING_AJAX) { return; }
I can see in the browser that my Ajax call is happening, and I see the 302 re-direct to our home page.

Here's my PHP and JS code for completeness' sake:
    function updateAvailability(e){
        var active_select = document.getElementById("availability_" + e);
        var newAvailability = active_select.value;
        var respJSON = "";
        console.log('display_user_company_products updating availability for product: ' + e + ' to : ' + newAvailability);
        jQuery.ajax({
             type : "post",
             dataType : "json",
             url : "https://xxxxxx/wp_admin/admin-ajax.php",
             data : {'action': 'update_product_master', 'product_id': e, 'attribute': 'current_availability', 'value': newAvailability, },
             success: function(response) {
                respJSON = JSON.stringify(response);
                console.log('display_user_company_products AJAX call returned : ' + respJSON);
                if(response.type == "success") {
                   alert("Thank you for updating your info!");
                }
                else {
                respJSON = JSON.stringify(response);
                   alert("Your update could not be processed");
                }
             }
        });
    }

// Create admin-ajax function to update product master attributes based on call from B2B Portal
add_action("wp_ajax_update_product_master", "ajax_update_product_master",1);
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_update_product_master", "ajax_update_product_master",1);
function ajax_update_product_master() {
    if (!$product_id) {
        $product_id = isset($_POST['product_id'])?$_POST['product_id']:isset($_GET['product_id'])?$_GET['product_id']:0;
    }
    if (!$attribute) {
        $attribute = isset($_POST['attribute'])?$_POST['attribute']:isset($_GET['attribute'])?$_GET['attribute']:0;
    }
    if (!$value) {
        $value = isset($_POST['value'])?$_POST['value']:isset($_GET['value'])?$_GET['value']:0;
    }
    error_log("Function ajax_update_product_master updating product master : ".$product_id." attribute : ".$attribute." with value : ".$value);
    $result = array('success'=> 1,
                    'message'=>'Function ajax_update_product_master updating product master '.$cigar_id.' attribute '.$attribute.' with value '.$value);
    return json_encode($result);
}

I'm completely stumped why admin-ajax never runs my php function above, but instead re-directs my call to our homepage.  What kind of methodical process can I use to diagnose what is causing these re-directs?
I tried the code included above, and was expecting my PHP function ajax_update_product_master to be executed by WP admin-ajax, but instead received a 302 re-direct to homepage.

deactivate all other plugin to see if you have the same result.

Thanks, but no luck trying that test.  What really puzzles me is the fact that another plugin is using admin-ajax without being re-directed.  To me this suggests it's not something in the environment re-directing all admin-ajax requests, but rather I've done something wrong in my code above.

I can see from the console msgs and network traffic that my JS function is running, and it is making the AJAX call, but then gets re-directed and my PHP function is never called.  I've tried changing the AJAX call from POST to GET but still same result.  I've considered writing my own process page rather than using WP admin-ajax, but again I ask myself, why would that be necessary when the other plugin is making admin-ajax calls with no problem?

if you just send json, I recommend to create a new api endpoint but I know this doesn't solve your problem. maybe there is something strange in the .htaccess file ?

Thanks again for your suggestions - unfortunately it turned out as I expected.  My AJAX calls to my own processor get re-directed just like those I make to the WP admin-ajax.  Any idea how i can figure out what is causing these re-directs?

In my latest test, I asked myself if results might be different if I did an xhr from JS without using JQuery.  Indeed they are - my Ajax call now is not re-directed, and gets delivered to WP admin-ajax.  However the payload of my POST isn't reaching the target, so I get a 400 response because $_REQUEST is empty.  It's very bizarre as I can see the payload on the client side

A friend helped me tweak a few things and this is now working, using JQuery and WP admin-ajax.  My biggest problem was the failure to localize my script correctly.

Great that you got it to work. Please only post well formulated answers. In this case please either edit your post to share more information on how you fixed the issue or remove it entirely. You can also edit your question outlining, that you got help.
